# How to clone a <tr> element without data but only the structure by using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html-table, clone

Is there a quick way to clone a `<tr>` element without its content in cells? Basically to have a pure `<tr>` element having only the same structure as the original?

Comment: Do you mean a deep clone or a shallow one?

Comment: By deep clone, you mean all the child elements within table cells?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want a deep clone of the element without the text content, you can write something like:

```
var $cloned = $("tr").clone().children().text("").end();
```

Comment: Nice one - what's the `end()` in the end for?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, it's here so `$cloned` will reference the cloned `<tr>` element instead of the elements matched by `find("*")`.

Comment: Will this return `tr`s in the original state i.e. with the original text? Confused reading this http://api.jquery.com/end/

Comment: @TheSuperTramp, it will return the cloned `<tr>` element without the original text. `end()` only allows to revert the set of matched elements to its previous state. You can translate the line as *match the table row, clone it, then match all its (cloned) descendants, set their inner text to the empty string, then forget about them and go back to the cloned table row, and return that*.

Comment: Cheers, yet another thing I learned... to clear any doubt here is live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/Tysb7/